# .htaccess allow only user-agents that contain a specific word

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent

I would like to know if there is a way to block all user-agents except the one that contains the word "chrome" using .htaccess

I used something like this, but this works unfortunately only if the exact name is given..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Lynx/2\.8\.8dev\.12 [NC]

RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !chrome [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```